# I grails migration plugin dbm-update saying "validation error"

Tags: grails

I have a hand written migration.
when I try to run it as:

```
grails dbm-update
```

I am getting this error:

```
validation Error
```

**database-migration version:1.3.8**

*How can I run the migration plugin to be more verbose with the error message?*

Update:
I just tried to run the app and get this error

```
columnDataType is required, 093-add-Type-field.groovy::1418895018124-1::authorName (generated)::(Checksum: 3:81d125287730881fdb5d52cdbd198f68)
```

but I have defined the data type:

```
    column(name: "type", type: "varchar(255)") {
                    constraints(nullable: "true")
                }
.
.
addNotNullContraint(tableName: "tableName",columnName:"type");
```

Answer (score 2):

sorry the problem was with the `addNotNullContraint`

I am using **Mysql** db so **type** field is *required*

so this is correct:

```
addNotNullContraint(tableName: "tableName",columnName:"type",columnDataType:"varchar(255)");
```

instead of:

```
addNotNullContraint(tableName: "tableName",columnName:"type");
```

details here [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/add_not_null_constraint.html)